# Why can't I edit my own deleted questions?

Tags: bug, editing, deleted-questions

I recently asked a question, thought about it, decided to delete it, and I wanted to add a short note after deleting it explaining why I removed the question.

It turns out, I couldn't edit the deleted question. I searched for my other deleted questions (being a 10k user, I can do that), and it turns out that I cannot edit any of them. I can edit my deleted answers, though.

<del>Moreover, this is unique to MathOverflow. On Math.SE it seems that I can edit my deleted questions just fine.</del>

Comment: I have also been annoyed by this issue. Suppose I write a nonsense answer (er, hypothetically, cough, cough..), post it, and then recognize that it is nonsense, so I delete immediately. But now I can't erase the nonsense without first undeleting! So I do that very quickly, hoping nobody sees the nonsense while I am erasing it.

Comment: Wait a sec...Asaf says he can edit his deleted answers, Joel says he can't. Have we found the long-awaited contradiction that proves the Universe is inconsistent?

Comment: @GerryMyerson All I see is a proof that Asaf $\ne$ Joel.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, I can see that. I can't seem to edit my own deleted questions. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30909/stone-von-neumann-mackey-theorem for example.

Comment: it's also an issue on MO Meta:, the "edit" button is greyed out for my own question: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3228/can-i-edit-my-own-deleted-questions

Comment: @Carlo: I seem to be able to edit your post.

Comment: yes, that's the weird part: the "edit" button is only greyed out if it is your own question, I can edit your questions and you can edit mine, but not the other way around.

Comment: If I understand [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178760/couple-of-issues-with-roomba-turbocharging/179555#179555) correctly, users are not able to edit *self-deleted* questions (this behavior should be the same on any site in SE network). You should be able to edit self-deleted answers. (However, it bumps the question.) And you should be able to edit an answer which was deleted for other reasons, not self-deleted.

Comment: @Martin: But I can edit self deleted questions on MSE.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I tried to search for my deleted questions on math.SE and meta.math.SE, and I cannot edit  them. If you are able to edit *your own questions* which were *deleted by yourself*, then it is a bug. (At least if we take the post on meta.SE as the official documentation.) Perhaps I should add that I have learned about this from [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23285#23286).

Comment: @Martin: Huh, now it seems I can't edit self-deleted questions on MSE. The reason it seemed that I can is that at some point one moderator had tried something out, and undeleted/re-deleted that question. I just realized that.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins As far as I can tell, you should be able to edit self-deleted *answers*. (See the posts linked above.) The disadvantage is that edit to a deleted answer still bumps the question. If you check [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1860237/revisions) and [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1860237/timeline) of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860006/find-x-where-x-32-1-geq-x235/1860237#1860237) on math.SE, you can see that I edited it after I deleted it. And I guess other users are able to provide similar examples here on MO.

Comment: @MartinSleziak You seem to be right. When I search for some of my own deleted answers now, it seems that I can edit them. But I have definitely had the experience of wanting to edit a deleted post and not being able to do so. Was it only with self-deleted questions? I guess so.